# Rogue black-box java application not responding to standard input redirect

Tags: java, batch-file, redirect, io, black-box

I have an external java application (blackbox), which requires authentication. I need to run this application in a batch setting, but it seems to be reading from standard input in some nonstandard way. That is, if I set the calling of the program to redirect STDIN to a file (`... <password.txt`) or pipe data to it (`echo mypasword | ...`), it does not recognize the input. As I run it, also, it seems to intercept `Cntrl+c` and `Cntrl+d` and `Cntrl+z` as legitimate password characters, so it must be doing something odd and not just reading from standard in.

Any idea what this application could be doing to read in input? I need to be able to send it information programmatically, and I'm stumped for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to take a look at the source code.
If you do not have this available and can not be provided to you, then you could try a [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). Provided whoever wrote the program did not obfuscate the source code, you should be able to figure out what happens from the decompiled sources.